# Severity: Notice Message: Undefined offset: 1. Found this error while working with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working with codeigniter. I cannot find any error with the code below, yet this line `if($split['1'] == $param)`throws an error "Severity: Notice Message: Undefined offset: 1". I checked echoing the value which outputs the exact value. Something seems to go wrong inside the if condition. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

```
$myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!"); 
if ($myfile) {
while(!feof($myfile)) {
    $split = explode(',',fgets($myfile),2);
    //echo  $split['1'];
    if($split['1'] == $param){
    echo $split['0'];
      }      
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have an empty line in file?
try it

```
while(!feof($myfile)) {
    $line = trim(fgets($myfile));
    if(strlen($line) == 0) continue;
    $split = explode(',',$line,2);
    //echo  $split['1'];
    if($split['1'] == $param){
    echo $split['0'];
      }      
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Hedin! excellent..It worked wonders. Could you please let me know what the problem was?

Comment: you have an empty line in newfile.txt or BOM signature

Answer (score 0):

Can use isset to check that key is present or not before processing. Also, its good to check $split is not empty before processing.

```
$myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!"); 
if ($myfile) {
while(!feof($myfile)) {
    $split = explode(',',fgets($myfile),2);

    if ($split) {
       if(isset($split['1'] && $split['1'] == $param){
         echo $split['0'];
       }
    }      
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Naincy. Thanks for the check.But when echoing, it outputs the value so it cannot be that there is no key '1'. Any more thought about this please?

Comment: its not only one case if its echoing its fine. But in some case that might be is not there. So you can use isset to check.